# ASP.NET Race Conditions

Tags: asp.net, locking, race-condition

What's the best way to prevent two different people from executing the same method at the same time?  Example, user A is on the same page as user B.  Both press the button on the page at the exact same time executing the code for that event.  I'm trying to make one wait for the other one to finish.

Is there a common way for doing this?

Here's some more info..

This is for a simple game where you buy members of the site (like the Owned game on FB).  The querystring is the ID of the user.  I'm having a problem where two people are clicking buy at the same time.  One gets the user and the other just loses money.  So I'm trying to prevent buying at the exact same time to stop that from happening.

Comment: you could use `lock` on an static variable but this sounds like you would be creating a contention point your application. What if instead 2 there are a 100 users on the page?

Comment: Can we know about the method and what it's doing?  Generally, each request made to a service (RESTful, ideally) is an atomic unit handled on its own.  It usually isn't dependent on other requests, especially requests made in other user contexts, for anything.  It's likely that there's a better way to architect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) instance will be created for each request, so assuming that the logic you have is in an instance member and does not access anything that is shared, no locking is required.

If hitting a shared resource, there are a few ways that you could enforce locking. One way would be to use a [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement e.g.

```
private static someObject = new Object();

public void SomeMethod() 
{
    lock(someObject) 
    {
        // do something with your shared resource.
    }

}
```

Generally speaking, you should aim to avoid using locks as much as possible (although there are many situations where a lock is required).

**EDIT:**

If you're holding your data in a data source that supports transactions e.g. like a database, then you would first want to check that what a user is attempting to buy hasn't already been bought in the time between the user clicking "yes" on the page and your application receiving the response. So, you need to check the data source to see if it hasn't already been bought and if it hasn't, then "buy" the item for the user. This should be done inside of a transaction so that it is atomic and therefore you only take money from the user's account if the action of "buying" the item is successful.

Answer (score 3):

You could decorate it with the [`[MethodImpl]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

This way only one thread can execute the method and others will wait. It is equivalent to putting a `lock` to the entire method body.

Comment: Watch out for creating deadlocks if you use this method.

Comment: According to Jeffrey Richter and his book "CLR via C#" 3rd ed., one is recommended to never use this attribute. This attribute makes use of the Monitor lock on the `this` variable, which is not recommended. Instead it's recommended to create a private instance field to lock on. If it's a static method, the attribute uses the Monitor class to lock on a reference to the type's type object, which is also not recommended and can lead to subtle bugs and problems.